# Dependabot/Snyk tool like for Rust and/or Elixir languages

Tags: security, github, rust, elixir, snyk

We have used both [Dependabot](https://dependabot.com/) and [Snyk](https://snyk.io/) to detect vulnerabilities in our [GitHub](https://github.com/) hosted code repositories but they only support some (NodeJS, Java, JavaScript, Kotlin and Swift) of the current languages we are working on, so the question here is what kind of tool for such tasks should we consider either for [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) ([cargo.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html)) or [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/) ([mix.exs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html)) languages if there exists one for those.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/nccgroup/sobelow ?

Comment: Very good repo @Everett but that tool is to be invoked manually (or in a CI/CD environment), and what I'm looking is something that actually analyzes our GitHub repos either as a whole Organization, or commit based as actions, and created the proper PRs if possible. Maybe I wasn't 100% clear/accurate on the initial description, but that's what both Snyk and Dependabot do.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't know what the restrictions are on how other apps run within the Github ecosystem.  Sometimes an intermediary app is required to run tools like that.

Answer (score 3):

1/ Dependabot does now support Rust and Elixir.

> what I'm looking is something that actually analyzes our GitHub repos either as a whole Organization

2/ [Since July 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-13-enable-dependabot-dependency-graph-and-other-security-features-across-your-organization/)

> ### Enable Dependabot, dependency graph, and other security features across your organization

> You can now enable or disable the dependency graph, Dependabot alerts, Dependabot security updates, and secret scanning for all repositories in an organization with one click. You can also set whether each feature will be enabled or disabled for newly-created repositories.
> Look for the "`Security & analysis`" tab in your organization settings page and on your [user settings page](https://github.com/settings/security_analysis).
>
> In addition, we've consolidated the repository-level settings for dependency graph, Dependabot alerts, Dependabot security updates, and secret scanning to a "Security & analysis" tab in the repository settings page.
>
> [Learn more in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-security-and-analysis-settings-for-your-organization)

Comment: Excelente news!!  Thanks a lot @VonC

Comment: @gvasquez Well, thanks to GitHub, which continues to lead on this topic.